# Prolog Bubblesort Uninstantiated Arguments

Tags: prolog, bubble-sort

I am working on a bubblesort algorithm in prolog. Here is what I have so far:

```
bubblesort([],SortedList).
bubblesort([X,Y|List], [Y,X|SortedList]) :- X>Y, bubblesort(List, SortedList).
bubblesort([N|List], [N|SortedList]) :- bubblesort(List, SortedList).

bubble(List, SortedList) :- bubblesort(List, Sorted),
                         ( check(Sorted)
                         -> SortedList=Sorted
                         ; bubble(Sorted, SortedList) ).
check([]).
check([X,Y|SortedList]) :- X<Y, check(SortedList).
```

I test this function with this call:

```
bubble([2, 11, -4, 6, 8, 10101, 61, -98, 55, 79, -32, -67, 54, 45, 19, 707, 43, -99, 32, 20], List).
```

The first time it sorts, it works fine. However, when it tries to sort the result of the first, this error occurs:

```
猭ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (21) bubblesort([32|_G3208], _G3265) ? creep
   Exception: (19) bubblesort([707, -99, 20, 32|_G3208], _G3256) ? creep
   Exception: (17) bubblesort([54, 19, 43, 707, -99, 20, 32|_G3208], _G3247) ? creep
   Exception: (15) bubblesort([79, -67, 45, 54, 19, 43, 707, -99|...], _G3238) ? creep
   Exception: (14) bubblesort([55, -32, 79, -67, 45, 54, 19, 43|...], _G3232) ? creep
   Exception: (13) bubblesort([10101, -98, 55, -32, 79, -67, 45, 54|...], _G3226) ? creep
   Exception: (10) bubblesort([11, 6, 8, 61, 10101, -98, 55, -32|...], _G3214) ? creep
   Exception: (9) bubblesort([2, -4, 11, 6, 8, 61, 10101, -98|...], _G3309) ? creep
```

Tracing the program shows that when this call is made:

```
Call: (21) bubblesort([32|_G5214], _G5271) ? creep
Call: (22) 32>_G5273 ? creep
```

the error message occurs. I don't understand how this call could have been made, since there aren't supposed to be unsubstantiated values in my list. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I revised the code slightly:

```
bubblesort([],[]).
bubblesort([X,Y|List], [Y,X|SortedList]) :- X>Y, bubblesort(List, SortedList).
bubblesort([N|List], [N|SortedList]) :- bubblesort(List, SortedList).

bubble(List, SortedList) :- bubblesort(List, Sorted),
                         ( check(Sorted)
                         -> SortedList=Sorted
                         ; bubble(Sorted, SortedList) ).
check([]).
check([X,Y|SortedList]) :- X<Y, check(SortedList).
```

I have the following output:
List = [-4, 2, -98, 6, -32, 8, -67, 11, 45|...]

This output is erroneous, and I know why this is the output. The check tests the first two, than moves on to the next two, etc, which is not desirable. I'm working on a fix for check.

Edit 2:

I revised the check method:

```
check([]).
check([_]).
check([X,Y|SortedList]) :- X<Y, check([Y|SortedList]).
```

The code works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code. See above for how I arrived at the answer to my own question:

```
bubblesort([],[]).
bubblesort([X],[X]).
bubblesort([X,Y|List], [Y,X|SortedList]) :- X>Y, bubblesort(List, SortedList).
bubblesort([N|List], [N|SortedList]) :- bubblesort(List, SortedList).

bubble(List, SortedList) :- bubblesort(List, Sorted),
                         ( check(Sorted)
                         -> SortedList=Sorted
                         ; bubble(Sorted, SortedList) ).
check([]).
check([_]).
check([X,Y|SortedList]) :- X<Y, check([Y|SortedList]).
```